# Multi-select add selected attribute if the value is present in the main array - php

Tags: php, wordpress, array-intersect

I am working with a multi-select and GET method.I want multiple options selected when the form is reloaded after submitted based on the $_GET method from url parametres.i have associated URL parametres is `cuisine%5B%5D=indian&cuisine%5B%5D=thai`.Actually multi-select is about `cuisine`.

### And my codes are below:

```
 <select name="cuisine[]" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-selected-text-format="count > 3" data-done-button="true" data-done-button-text="OK" multiple>
    <?php
        $selected_cuisine = $_GET['cuisine'];
        // Get all cuisines list by get_terms() function.Its built in wordpress
        $restaurant_cuisines = get_terms('cuisine', array('hide_empty' => false));
        $cuisines = array();
        foreach ($restaurant_cuisines as $restaurant_cuisine) {
            // echo $restaurant_cuisine;
            array_push( $cuisines, $restaurant_cuisine->slug );
            // echo $cuisines_list;
        }
        print_r ($selected_cuisine);
        print_r($cuisines);
        if(array_intersect($selected_cuisine, $cuisines)){
            $selected = 'selected';
        }else{
            $selected = '';
        }
        foreach ($restaurant_cuisines as $cuisine) {
            echo '<option value="'. $cuisine->slug .'" '. $selected .' >'. $cuisine->name .'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

But the problem is that every options is getting selected.Actually there is total `3 cuisines : indian, thai & chainese` and `2 of them are selected` -> `indian and thai`.But problem is 3 options are selected. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember when you are using `array_intersect` it is setting true is at least one match in both array.So everything is getting selected.Rather you can try this:

```
<select name="cuisine[]" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-selected-text-format="count > 3" data-done-button="true" data-done-button-text="OK" multiple>
<?php
    $selected_cuisine = $_GET['cuisine'];
    // Get all cuisines list by get_terms() function.Its built in wordpress
    $restaurant_cuisines = get_terms('cuisine', array('hide_empty' => false));
    $cuisines = array();
    foreach ($restaurant_cuisines as $restaurant_cuisine) {
        array_push( $cuisines, $restaurant_cuisine->slug );
    }
    foreach ($restaurant_cuisines as $cuisine) {
        if(in_array($cuisine->slug, $selected_cuisine)){
          $selected = 'selected';
        }else{
          $selected = '';
        }
        echo '<option value="'. $cuisine->slug .'" '. $selected .' >'. $cuisine->name .'</option>';
    }
?>
```